# How can I create a command on Win10 to open the "Folder and Search Options" window on the second tab?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

### Background

---

I'm big on customizing my context menus, and I have edited the registry to include a context menu item that appears when you right click the background of a directory. The context menu is called "Change Folder and Search Opetions". See this image:

[image: Context Menu]

What it does, is open the following window:

[image: Window1]

Here is what the entry looks like in RegEdit:

[image: RegEdit Screenshot]

Here is code for the entry if anyone else wants to use it themselves:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Windows.folderoptions]
"CommandStateSync"=""
"ExplorerCommandHandler"="{83bb272f-7d5e-4b6e-9250-889893f0dac7}"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,-274"
"MUIVerb"="Folder Options"
"Description"="@shell32.dll,-31449"
"Position"="Bottom"
```

### Question

---

Hopefully you're still with me. My question is if there is any way to customize this registry entry to open the `Folder and Search Options` window to the **second tab** (*View*). I want it to open, by default, this page:

[image: Folder and Search Options 2]

Is this possible? I'm hoping someone with knowledge of Windows internals has a solution.

I'm also definitely open to solutions that use PowerShell, VBS, and/or Batch Files, because I can just call them from the registry instead of using the current registry entry.

I use this shortcut a lot to quickly switch folder views and having it open to the page I'm interested in would save time.

Any help greatly appreciated!

### Edit 1:

---

@harrymc Posted a partial solution that uses the following commend:

`rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 7`

Unfortunately while this does bring up the correct window and tab, it doesn't pass along the current folder to the dialog and the ability to modify the `Folder Views > Apply to Folders` option (What I need) is grayed out.

I need a solution that does pass along the folder so I can quickly change default folder views.

I think the final solution might need to be a registry entry. (Could be wrong though)

Answer (score 0):

This command will open the View tab :

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 7
```

You may incorporate this command into your registry modifications.

Reference :
[List of Rundll32 Commands in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77458-rundll32-commands-list-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, while that does open the correct window, the ability to modify the "Folder Views" section is grayed out. I have a feeling that this approach doesn't pass along the current folder to the window. Thanks for the help though. I'll update my post.